# I made some annotations (not grease pencil!). Where is the menu to remove / hide / edit them?

Tags: 3d-view, visibility, annotation

I used the ***Annotate*** tool to make some annotations in the 3D viewport.

[image]

I would like to edit, hide or remove them, but I can't find the annotate layers editor.

Comment: Asking and answering my own question because I've spent minutes looking for it in the scene / viewport / whatnot settings and in the annotate tool settings, to no avail. So I figured it could help somebody as a Q&A.

Answer (score 9):

Selecting again the *Annotate* tool will display a menu in the header. By default an annotation layer called "*Note*" is used.

From that menu, the layer visibility can be toggled, as well as adding / removing layers, and changing some little things like the color and the thickness.

[image]

Note: if the header is hidden, it can be displayed again using the little downwards arrow at the top margin of the 3D window.

[image]

---

Edit: ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍ ᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ made me realize that there is another, more natural, place where the menu can be found! The **3D viewport's sidebar** (aka "the <kbd>N</kbd> menu"), under *View > Annotations*

[image]

Comment: Just to add - it is *always* accesible through *Sidebar > View > Annotations* no matter which tool is selected :).

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ I believe you should post your comment as an answer. I'd accept that as it's clearly the most natural place to look for that feature.

Comment: So for example, if I make an annotation pointing to a node, and then I move that node, there is no way to later move that annotation layer? In other words, it needs to be redrawn each time the node setup changes? (If so, that is an unexpected and unfortunate limitation.)

Answer (score 3):

Another person described how to hide them, but to edit/remove parts you can hold LMB on the annotate widget and select the eraser tool.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the Header area and select Show Tool Settings.  I was trying to find the solution as well and came across the instructions in the Blender Manual:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/regions.html